# ajax doesn't work properly when call inside a function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to call a javascript function that I have the ajax request and it doesn't work because there is not any responseText however if I put the code outside the function is works like a charm. Someone could please explain how does it work?.

```js
//This is here work properly.
console.log("addPostmanUser");
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "email": "holahola@local.es",
  "password": "12345",
  "username": "holahola",
  "name": "holahola",
  "surname": "toledo",
  "birthDate": 687045600000,
  "enabled": true,
  "authorities": [],
  "groups": [],
  "character": null,
  "locale": null,
  "registrationToken": null,
  "facebookId": null,
  "pushToken": null,
  "termsDate": null
});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log("addPostmanUser response: ");
    console.log(xhr);
  }
});
xhr.open("POST", "http://IP/user", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.send(data);

//this one doesn't work
function inSameFile() {
  console.log("addPostmanUser");
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    "email": "holahola@local.es",
    "password": "12345",
    "username": "holahola",
    "name": "holahola",
    "surname": "toledo",
    "birthDate": 687045600000,
    "enabled": true,
    "authorities": [],
    "groups": [],
    "character": null,
    "locale": null,
    "registrationToken": null,
    "facebookId": null,
    "pushToken": null,
    "termsDate": null
  });
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log("addPostmanUser response: ");
      console.log(xhr);
    }
  });
  xhr.open("POST", "http://IP/user", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    <a class="enter" href="" onClick="inSameFile();" id="btn_register">Registrarme</a>
    <br>
    <a class="enter" href="" id="btn_cancel">Cancelar</a>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</form>
```

Comment: "there is not any responseText" — Please describe the behaviour you are experiencing in more detail. Does anything get output by the two `console.log` statements? Does the Developer Tools Network tab in the two requests show different data? (e.g. is one aborted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  <a class="enter" href="" onClick="inSameFile();" id="btn_register"   >Registrarme</a><br>
> ```

What happens when you click on a link?

1. A click event fires
2. JavaScript handles any events on it
3. The browser loads the page specified in the `href` (the current page in this case).

So one of two things is going to happen here:

Either the XHR request is going to happen too slowly, in which case it will be aborted before there is a response because the page hosting it will go away.

**or**

The XHR object will be logged to the console, then the new page will load. That will destroy the XHR object (because it existed on a page that has been left behind) and make it impossible to inspect the contents of it (despite the summary still being shown in the Console if you have log preservation turned on).

---

If you want something for people to click on to trigger JavaScript then either invest the effort into building a [decent solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (with server side fallbacks and the use of `preventDefault` if the JS is successful) **or** take the quick and dirty option of using a button instead of a link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem was that you have mentioned at 3rd point and what you have explained about XHR object, the href was loading the same page and it was destroying the request.  
I also have in mind the Unobtrusive JavaScript. In this case i have a separate javascript file contains the all functions and event listener. (The above example was just for explain my problem)